# ¿Cómo almacenar resultados por rondas competitivas en un campeonato de futbol?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Estoy aprendiendo Python y como tarea estoy simulando un campeonato de futbol y la obtencion de los goles. Lo hice muy facil pero no se como ALMACENAR RESULTADOS POR RONDAS. He tratado varias cosas pero no he concretado

Les pongo aca la parte del codigo que habia realizado,solo 4 equipos creo que es bastante dolor de cabeza jaja, mi objetivo final es 8 grupos de 4 equipos con las respectivas condiciones para seleccionar, etc,

Teniendo los resultados de los partidos en las rondas queria ir sumando las estadisticas de los resultados por equipos. Por ejemplo: Cuba--> jj g p e gF gC p /Argentina-->jj g p e gF gC p, etc..(juegos jugados, ganados, perdidos, empates, goles a favor, goles en contra, puntos) ...o sea cada vez que un equipo juegue un partido en una ronda ir almacenando sus estadisicas...gracias por su tiempo... –

```
import random

grupoA = ['Argentina', 'Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Cuba']

def CajitaGolesA(a,b):

    goles1 = random.choice(range(0,5))
    goles2 = random.choice(range(0,5))

    if goles1 == goles2:
        print('Empate',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',grupoA[b],':',goles2)

    elif goles1 > goles2:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',grupoA[b],':',goles2)

    else:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[a],':',goles2,'vs',grupoA[b],':',goles1)

print('GRUPO A')
print('primera ronda')
CajitaGolesA(0,1)
CajitaGolesA(2,3)

print('segunda ronda')
CajitaGolesA(1,2)
CajitaGolesA(3,0)

print('tercera ronda')
CajitaGolesA(0,2)
CajitaGolesA(3,1)
```

Comment: sería interesante que explicaras qué te falla y cómo quieres que sea el resultado. Es decir, dar datos técnicos del problema para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Teniendo los resultados de los partidos en las rondas queria ir sumando las estadisticas de los resultados por equipos. Por ejemplo: Cuba--> jj g p e gF gC p /Argentina-->jj g p e gF gC p, etc..(juegos jugados, ganados, perdidos, empates, goles a favor, goles en contra, puntos) ...o sea cada vez que un equipo juegue un partido en una ronda ir almacenando sus estadisicas...gracias por su tiempo...

Comment: Dale a [edit] para ofrecer estos jugosos detalles en el cuerpo de la pregunta

Comment: Hace un par de horas, en mi respuesta, agregué una modificación donde se computan los puntos y los goles a favor y en contra. A medida que vas incluyendo más estadísticas, sería más fácil de trabajar esto con una base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.Claro!. Pienso que el ejercio está bueno, no lo creen? Cómo sería con POO y base de datos?, es que, la evolución es importante, pues a los principiantes como yo nos resultaria productivo ver las similitudes, diferencias y puntos fuertes de las dos orientaciones de programación..y asi poder extrapolar en el futuro...gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basandome en lo que habías hecho, puse una función `crear_calendario()` que crea un calendario muy simple de juegos entre todos los equipos, siguiendo tu lógica de `0-1, 2-3, 1-2, 3-0, 0-2 y 3-1` por cada grupo.
Como cada grupo tiene 4 equipos, entonces serán 3 jornadas, o rondas.
La función devolverá un diccionario, donde cada elemento es un partido de la `Ronda X`:

```
todos_partidos = {
'Ronda 1': 
[('GRUPO A', 'Argentina', 'Mexico'), 
('GRUPO A', 'Colombia', 'Cuba'), 
('GRUPO B', 'Brasil', 'Peru'), 
('GRUPO B', 'Ecuador', 'Venezuela')], 
'Ronda 2': 
[('GRUPO A', 'Mexico', 'Colombia'),
... etc }
```

Ese diccionario es pasado a la función `jugar_calendario()`, donde se va a calcular un resultado según tu lógica de seleccionar un valor aleatorio entre `0 y 5`.
Cada valor es acumulado en otro diccionario `resultados` donde cada índice corresponde al país y el valor una lista con los puntos y goles de cada ronda, de este modo:

```
resultados = {
Pais1 : [(ptos_p1, GF_p1, GC_p1), (pts_p2, GF_p2, GC_p2), (pts_p3, GF_p3, GC_p3)],
Pais2 : [(ptos_p1, GF_p1, GC_p1), (pts_p2, GF_p2, GC_p2), (pts_p3, GF_p3, GC_p3)],
... etc}
```

Con ese resultado ya puedes hacer otros cálculos posteriores como calcular una tabla clasificatoria.

Aquí el código, puedes agregar más grupos, solo añadiendo otro elemento con el formato
`'GRUPO X': ['pais1', 'pais2', 'pais3', 'pais4']`
al diccionario equipos (no olvides la coma para separar los elementos)

```
import random

def realizar_partido():
    goles1 = random.choice(range(0,5))
    goles2 = random.choice(range(0,5))
    if goles1 > goles2:
        puntos1 = 3
        puntos2 = 0
    elif goles1 < goles2:
        puntos1 = 0
        puntos2 = 3
    else:
        puntos1 = 1
        puntos2 = 1
    # goles1 son los GF del equipo 1 y GC del equipo 2. Y viceversa
    return [(puntos1, goles1, goles2), (puntos2, goles2, goles1)]

def jugar_calendario(partidos):
    resultados = {}
    for ronda, matches in partidos.items():
        print("========== {} ==========".format(ronda))
        for match in matches:
            grupo = match[0]
            pais1 = match[1]
            pais2 = match[2]
            r = realizar_partido()
            print("{} -> {} {} - {} {}".format(grupo, pais1, r[0][1], r[1][1], pais2))
            # Guardar los resultados en otro diccionario
            if pais1 not in resultados:
                resultados[pais1] = [r[0]]
                resultados[pais2] = [r[1]]
            else:
                resultados[pais1].append(r[0])
                resultados[pais2].append(r[1])
        print()
    return resultados

def crear_calendario(equipos):
    todos_partidos = {}
    for grupo, paises in equipos.items():
        # Todos los partidos de un grupo, esto puede ser creado por permutación, pero 
        # se va a hacer de esta forma para hacerlo más facil
        ronda1 = [(grupo, paises[0], paises[1]), (grupo, paises[2], paises[3])]
        ronda2 = [(grupo, paises[1], paises[2]), (grupo, paises[3], paises[0])]
        ronda3 = [(grupo, paises[0], paises[2]), (grupo, paises[3], paises[1])]
        # Ahora agregar los elementos a un diccionario con todos los partidos
        if 'Ronda 1' not in todos_partidos:
            # Si no existe en elemento en el diccionario, crearlo
            todos_partidos['Ronda 1'] = [ronda1[0], ronda1[1]]
            todos_partidos['Ronda 2'] = [ronda2[0], ronda2[1]]
            todos_partidos['Ronda 3'] = [ronda3[0], ronda3[1]]
        else:
            # Si existe, agregar estos elementos al final de cada item
            todos_partidos['Ronda 1'].extend([ronda1[0], ronda1[1]])
            todos_partidos['Ronda 2'].extend([ronda2[0], ronda2[1]])
            todos_partidos['Ronda 3'].extend([ronda3[0], ronda3[1]])
    return todos_partidos


# #######################
equipos = {\
'GRUPO A':['Argentina', 'Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Cuba'], \
'GRUPO B':['Brasil', 'Peru', 'Ecuador', 'Venezuela']}
# ###
calendario = crear_calendario(equipos)
tabla_resultados = jugar_calendario(calendario)
#imprimir los resultados de goles por pais
print("========== RESULTADOS ==========")
#print(tabla_resultados)
for pais, resultados in tabla_resultados.items():
    pais = pais.ljust(12, ' ') # Esto es solo para hacer una tabulacion
    puntos = 0
    GF = 0
    GC = 0
    for values in resultados:
        puntos += values[0]
        GF += values[1]
        GC += values[2]
    print("{} -> PTS: {} | GF: {} | GC: {}".format(pais, puntos, GF, GC))
```

Como podrás notar, en el diccionario de salida, cada 4 elementos seguidos es un grupo, así que puedes hacer una lógica para calcular los clasificados u otras cosas.

Comment: wow. hoy por la tarde lo probare sin duda. y despues entenderlo y dominarlo pues hay mucho que desconozco aca...para dar el próximo salto..hacerlo con POO y manejarlo con una base de datos debería ser factible también no...Cuál es su opinión acerca de cómo sería mejor resolver este problema?

Comment: Sería una respuesta basada en opiniones, algo que no gusta mucho en el sitio, pero la forma menos complicada es hacerlo con base de datos y si es posible POO. Sin embargo como estas aprendiendo tienes que dominar bien los conceptos, los arreglos de datos y la programación funcional antes de ir por lo otro.

Comment: Definitivamente me siento satisfecho con el codigo que has puesto...ya lo estoy estudiando, ahora a desarmarlo y armarlo.Mantengo la propuesta que hago sobre , hacer lo mismo pero con POO y bases de datos. y mas en un tema como este de almacenar resultados etc. Huelo material para varias clases onlines...creo que eres bueno eh...saludos cordiales

Comment: Continuando con el tema..y el apendizaje encuentro lo siguiente: