# Como almacenar resultados en forma de tablas que se actualicen?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Teniendo el siguiente codigo debe ser facil almacenar los resultados. Se trata de cuatro equipos de Futbol que juegan entre ellos, 3 rondas, y se quisiera saber el resultado de los cuatro equipos CADA VEZ QUE FINALICE UNA RONDA.
por ejemplo ronda 1 
cuba vs argentina resultado almacenado en un diccionario
mexico vs colombia resultado almacenado en un diccionario

resultados  jj g p e gf gc puntos

argentina

mexico

cuba

colombia

que haga eso por cada ronda

porque eso despues se desea hacer para 32 equipos, 8 grupos de cuatro, como si fuera un mundial y despues aplicarle los if pertinentes

sin embargo mi principal dificultad radica en el almacenamiento de los resultados, que sugieren que deberia leerme, estudiar, etc??

considero importante el saber almacenar los resultados en cualquier codigo que pueda hacerse, sin embargo no encuentro con bibliografia adecuada, o esta delante de mi y no lo se apreciar...para poder encontrar las INVARIANTES DEL CONOCIMIENTO sobre como almacenar los resultados.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Nov 21 21:47:42 2019

@author: jotas
"""

import random

grupoA = ['Argentina', 'Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Cuba']

def CajitaGolesA(a,b):


    goles1 = random.choice(range(0,5))
    goles2 = random.choice(range(0,5))


    if goles1 == goles2:
        print('Empate',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',goles2,':',grupoA[b])
        d1 = {grupoA[a]:[0,0,1,goles1,goles2,1]}
        d2 = {grupoA[b]:[0,0,1,goles2,goles1,1]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()
    elif goles1 > goles2:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',goles2,':',grupoA[b])
        d1 = {grupoA[a]:[1,0,0,goles1,goles2,3]}
        d2 = {grupoA[b]:[0,0,1,goles2,goles1,0]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()

    else:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[b],':',goles2,'vs',goles1,':',grupoA[a])
        d1 = {grupoA[b]:[1,0,0,goles2,goles1,3]}
        d2 = {grupoA[a]:[0,0,1,goles1,goles2,0]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()



print('GRUPO A')
print('========== primera ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(0,1)
CajitaGolesA(2,3)

print('========== segunda ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(1,2)
CajitaGolesA(3,0)

print('========== tercera ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(0,2)
CajitaGolesA(3,1)
```

ya se ha indagado sobre el tema en esta pregunta en el siguiente link:

[¿Cómo almacenar resultados por rondas competitivas en un campeonato de futbol?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311239/c%c3%b3mo-almacenar-resultados-por-rondas-competitivas-en-un-campeonato-de-futbol?noredirect=1#comment566312_311239)

Gracias por su tiempo ..y paciencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TE recomiendo que estudies una libreria de python muy util para trabajar con datos: pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/
Aqui te dejo el codigo de lo que podrias hacer. Aprovecha y cuando estudies un poco lo puedes mejorar muchisimo, pues lo que hice fue introducir algunas modificaciones a tu codigo para que haga lo que pides.
El codigo genera cuatro archivos, tres con las estadisticas de cada ronda y uno con las estadisticas totale. Los archivos generados estan en formato csv y puedes abrirlos con exel o libreoffice si trabajas en linux. Si tienes algun problema al abrir el archivo en excel pues te aparecen todos los campos en una misma casilla, puede deberse al separador usado. Puedes corregir eso en la funcion

```
to_csv("filename.csv", index=False, sep=";")
```

Paraindicar el separador que quieras, por ejemplo, en este caso use el ;
Si tienes alguna duda no temas comentarla

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Nov 21 21:47:42 2019

@author: jotas
"""

import random
import pandas as pd
import copy

grupoA = ['Argentina', 'Mexico', 'Colombia', 'Cuba']

resultados = {"Resultados" : ["JJ", "G", "P", "E", "GF", "GC", "Puntos"]}

for pais in grupoA:
    resultados[pais] = [0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0]

resultados = {"Primera Ronda" : copy.deepcopy(resultados),
              "Segunda Ronda" : copy.deepcopy(resultados),
              "Tercera Ronda" : copy.deepcopy(resultados)}

print(resultados)

def CajitaGolesA(a,b,ronda):

    goles1 = random.choice(range(0,5))
    goles2 = random.choice(range(0,5))

    if goles1 == goles2:
        print('Empate',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',goles2,':',grupoA[b])
        d1 = {grupoA[a]:[0,0,1,goles1,goles2,1]}
        d2 = {grupoA[b]:[0,0,1,goles2,goles1,1]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()

        resultados[ronda][grupoA[a]] = [1,0,0,1,goles1,goles2,1]
        resultados[ronda][grupoA[b]] = [1,0,0,1,goles2,goles1,1]

    elif goles1 > goles2:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[a],':',goles1,'vs',goles2,':',grupoA[b])
        d1 = {grupoA[a]:[1,0,0,goles1,goles2,3]}
        d2 = {grupoA[b]:[0,1,0,goles2,goles1,0]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()

        resultados[ronda][grupoA[a]] = [1,1,0,0,goles1,goles2,3]
        resultados[ronda][grupoA[b]] = [1,0,1,0,goles2,goles1,0]

    else:
        print('Ha ganado',grupoA[b],':',goles2,'vs',goles1,':',grupoA[a])
        d1 = {grupoA[b]:[0,1,0,goles2,goles1,0]}
        d2 = {grupoA[a]:[1,0,0,goles1,goles2,3]}
        print()
        print('Estadisticas individuales del partido')
        print(d1)
        print(d2)
        print()

        resultados[ronda][grupoA[a]] = [1,0,1,0,goles1,goles2,0]
        resultados[ronda][grupoA[b]] = [1,1,0,0,goles2,goles1,3]


print('GRUPO A')
print('========== primera ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(0,1, "Primera Ronda")
CajitaGolesA(2,3, "Primera Ronda")

print('========== segunda ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(1,2, "Segunda Ronda")
CajitaGolesA(3,0, "Segunda Ronda")

print('========== tercera ronda ==========')
CajitaGolesA(0,2, "Tercera Ronda")
CajitaGolesA(3,1, "Tercera Ronda")

PrimeraRonda = pd.DataFrame(resultados["Primera Ronda"])
SegundaRonda = pd.DataFrame(resultados["Segunda Ronda"])
TerceraRonda = pd.DataFrame(resultados["Tercera Ronda"])

PrimeraRonda.to_csv("PrimeraRonda.csv", index=False)
SegundaRonda.to_csv("SegundaRonda.csv", index=False)
TerceraRonda.to_csv("TerceraRonda.csv", index=False)

ResultadoTotal = {"Resultados" : ["JJ", "G", "P", "E", "GF", "GC", "Puntos"]}

for pais in grupoA:
    ResultadoTotal[pais] = []
    for i in range(7):
        ResultadoTotal[pais].append(resultados["Primera Ronda"][pais][i] + resultados["Segunda Ronda"][pais][i] + resultados["Tercera Ronda"][pais][i])

ResultadoTotal = pd.DataFrame(ResultadoTotal)

ResultadoTotal.to_csv("ResultadoTotal.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Siiiii. jajaja. muy contento con la respuesta. Debo aclarar que otras personas dieron respuestas con las que quede muy satisfecho, pero, sin dudas esta se ajusta mas a mis pobres conocimientos ahora que soy aprendiz. El universo python tiene muchas rutas, imagino que una de las grandes habilidades es saber donde encontrar informacionn para poder resolver una problematica en particular. Dicho esto, muchas gracias por su tiempo...y si puede..que cree usted que deberia estudiar OBLIGATORIAMENTE independientemente de en que quiera trabajar despues relacionado con Python??

Comment: Python es un lenguaje muy vesatil y puede ser utilizado en muchas aristas. De mi poca experiencia te puedo recomendar algunas cositas. Si quieres trabajar con datos, no puedes dejar de revisar los paquetes numpy y matplotlib, asi como pandas. Si te interesa el munda de la inteligencia artificial, en el cual python es vanguardia, dale una ojeada a tensorflow y keras. Si te va mas el mundo de desarrollo web, no dudes en buscar informacion sobre el framework Django.

Comment: Asi lo hare,gracias por pasarte por aca. las opciones que mas me interesan supongo que son trabajr con datos y el framework Django..aunque  ahora estaba aprendiendo python basico..gracias de nuevo

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos